# A loop or something else for plotting using curve() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I'm trying to draw 3 overlaying curves (**please see my R code below**) in any 3 different colors (e.g., red, green, blue). I have tried the following but don't get neatly shaped plots.

Could this be looped easily in "R base"? Or there are some other possibilities?

```
 N  <- c(120, 528, 828)
df1 <- c(3, 3, 3)
df2 <- c(108, 516, 816)
 f  <- c(20, 20, 20) 


## 3 Plots:

Likelihood = curve( df(f, df1, df2, ncp = (x * N) / (1 - x) ) ,
  col = 'red4', lwd = 3, from = 0, to = 1, n = 1e4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a basic loop you could try something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(N)) {
    add <- if(i == 1) FALSE else TRUE
    curve( df(f[i], df1[i], df2[i], ncp = (x * N[i]) / (1 - x) ) ,
           col = i, lwd = 3, from = 0, to = 1, n = 1e4, add=add)
}
```

Not the prettiest but using the basics. You should definitely explore `ggplot2`.

To avoid that some curves not complete, you could first get the values for each curve, estimate their ranges and then plot them. For example:

```
# function to get the values of each curve
curve_ <- function(x, i) df(f[i], df1[i], df2[i], ncp = (x * N[i]) / (1 - x))

# estimate the values of each curve
curves <- lapply(1:length(N), function(i) {
    x <- seq(0,1,length.out = 1e4)
    curve_(x, i)
})

# estimate the ranges
ranges_ <- sapply(curves, range, na.rm=T)

# plot using the ranges as plotting parameters (ylim)
for (i in 1:length(curves)) {
    if(i == 1) {
        plot(curves[[i]], type='l', col=i, xlim=c(0,length(curves[[i]])), ylim=c(min(ranges_[1,]), max(ranges_[2,])))
    } else {
        lines(curves[[i]], col=i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to put the tallest one be plotted first and then the 2 other one be plotted after that?

Comment: Thank you, for color changes, should I be defining a separate vector?

Comment: Yes. You can define a vector with the colours and then use it with `col=color_vector[i]`

Comment: for (i in 1:10) plot(rnorm(10))

Comment: spadarian, can I send you an R file before asking a question, it is a loop question and everything works fine except when I want to get a png file for each "i", the png file come out blank?